# Tradução na janela de erro sobre intervalo de tempo para introdução de novo comentário

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Tinha um comentário muito longo que precisei dividir em dois.

Coloquei o primeiro sem problemas, mas ao colocar o segundo apareceu uma janela de erro a indicar-me que eu teria que aguardar 15 segundos:

[image: Captura de tela]

A questão aqui é a tradução do último paragrafo onde está escrito "Timer reiniciado", mas a tradução pode ser realizada em pleno utilizando:

### Contador reiniciado.

Ou, para o caso de devido ao tamanho da janela, o resultado final ser duas linhas de texto, podemos usar:

### Tempo reiniciado.

Comment: Essa pergunta não deveria estar com a tag status-pronto ou status-by-design?